# Set __name__ attribute using boost::python::make_function

Tags: python, c++, boost

I need access to the function name in a python object after creating it with make_function.

I tried this:

```
void foo() {}
boost::python::object function = boost::python::make_function(foo);

// I got "unnamed Boost.Python function"
std::string name = boost::python::extract<std::string>(function.attr("__name__"));

// I got "attribute '__name__' of 'Boost.Python.function'"
function.attr("__name__") = "foo";
```

Is it possible to set the "__name__" attribute using make_function?

Comment: I solved this problem not by using make_function butt `PyMethoDef`. For instance, `PyMethodDef * def = new PyMethodDef(); def->ml_name="foo"; ...`

Answer (score 0):

I often just make a real Python function with whatever properties I want, and have it call an internal function (starting with `_` to indicate it's not public) which I implement in C++.

Then you can do anything you want, and `help(foo)` and similar things will look more familiar because your visible function name is just a normal Python function.